# Unwind to a viewController that is not in the current navigation view controller chain

Tags: ios, unwind-segue

I have the following scenes in the `storyboard`

VC1 => NavC => VC2 => VC3 => VC4
I programmatically `segue` from VC1 to either VC2 or VC3 based on a condition (I am doing that by instantiating NavC and change the viewControllers array). 
Now I would like to unwind from VC4 to VC1, but I think I am doing something wrong, because it is ignored and nothing is happening.
To do this I have defined an `IBAction` called unwind1 in VC1, then I have created an exit `segue` from VC4 to its exit and called it segue1. I also have subclassed `UINavigationController` and have the following methods in it:

```
override func viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction(action: Selector, fromViewController: UIViewController, withSender sender: AnyObject!) -> UIViewController {
    return self.presentingViewController!
}

override func segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController: UIViewController, fromViewController: UIViewController, identifier: String?) -> UIStoryboardSegue {
    return UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: identifier, source: fromViewController, destination: toViewController)
}
```

In method1 of VC4 I make a call to `self.performSegueWithId("unwind1")`. Although when I trace the execution control reaches to this line but it is ignored. 
When I put breakpoint in the two above-mentioned methods, execution control never gets there.
Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you drag to the exit icon in VC4 you should see the `unwind1:` method listed.  Select that and that is all you should need to do.  Perhaps things are getting confused because your don't use segues to get to VC2/VC3.  It is probably better to embed both VC2 and VC3 in separate navigation controllers and then have different segues from VC1 to either VC2 or VC3

Comment: @Paulw11 I already did that and have chosen unwind1: when dragging. The question is that if I have two different nav controllers for VC2 and VC3, is the pushing and popping on the stack of VCs would be same as they are in the same nav controller? What about the navbar of the nav controller? Is it going to be inherited if I go from VC2 to VC3? I have customizations for navBar. Do I need to do that for both? –  AKH 9 mins ago

Comment: Ok, I just set up a test app.  Even if you have two nav controllers, when you segue from VC2 to VC3 you can segue directly to VC3, not the nav controller that VC3 is embedded in.  If you go from VC1 to VC3 you segue to the navcontroller that VC3 is embedded in.  You will need to ensure that you customise the navbar as required (i.e. when you enter VC2 or if you enter VC3 directly), but if you have already customised it for VC2 you don't need to customise it again for VC3

Comment: I just modified my test so that it manipulates the nav controller's viewControllers property in `prepareForSegue` and my unwind segue works correctly.  I didn't implement any code for the unwind aside from an empty `IBAction` method in the root view controller

Comment: Thank you. I should have done that test :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I have done is the correct solution to the problem, because I just noticed it works on ios 8.1, but it does not work on ios 8.0. I assume it is a bug in the iOS!

Comment: What I ended up doing is using NSNotification in order to send a message and just dismissed the topVC